# Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server regarding order tracking

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am looking for an efficient way to convert rows to columns in SQL server using Pivot. I used to export the query result to CSV file and then to get the ideal result with MS Excel. I am wondering if there's an efficient way with SQL to achieve the ideal result. Thank you so much. 
*Please understand I inserted 2 pictures because something wrong happened with the layout.

**Original Table**

[image: This is the original Table]

**Ideal result**

[image: This is ideal result]

Comment: The question is, are you sure if there are only three dates? Otherwise, we need to use a dynamic pivot.

Comment: There are thousands of rows actually, which covers many dates. It would be highly appreciated if you could show me how to use dynamic pivot. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Need clarification: For ID=1, there is no booking for 'Bizclass' on 4-22. Why is it '1' in the second row of your ideal result. If ID=1 has no 'Bizclass' type, do you need to include this row like '1,Bizclass,0,0,0,0....'. Another question is: are there only two booking_types?